# Unrecognized element '<runtime>' when upgrading Google App Engine to Java 8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8

I have a Google App Engine Standard server running Java 7, and would like to upgrade to Java 8. I have added `<runtime>java8</runtime>` to my `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>my-app</application>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    ...
```

This was described in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#specifying_the_java_8_runtime_for_your_app.

However when building the application, it fails with the error `Unrecognized element <runtime>`. Can anyone advise?

Comment: how are you building it?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Build is done by running the maven command `appengine:devserver` through Eclipse

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be using an old version of appengine sdk currently. Check whether you have the latest version of `appengine-api` dependency.

I use following `appengine-api` and it works fine for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.58</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using 1.9.60, and still couldn't get this working

Comment: @Turini, run `mvn dependency:tree` and check whether you have a dependency to any other appengine-api version by any chance.

Comment: thanks Lahiru. but it's only using the latest appengine-api and has no other references `[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.60:compile`

Comment: I can't this working either.  Same bug.  I've tried installing the latest app engine SDK and prepending it to my path.  I get the same unrecognized element: <runtime> error.

Comment: I just create another project from scratch, using the latest gae-API and JDK 8: it worked like a charm.  Maybe some kind of cache, or misconfiguration on my IDE. Importing all old code to this new project worked for me. It might help you also, user3562927. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue but it turned out to be that i was using the appengine-maven-plugin ( for debugging ) and i had to up its version too.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.49</version>
   <configuration>
      <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
      <jvmFlags>
          <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
           <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
       </jvmFlags>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an old version of Google Cloud SDK. You can update it as follows -

Step 1.
Right click on "Google Cloud SDK Shell" and click "Run as administrator"

Step 2.
Run following command on command prompt opened -

gcloud components update

Congratulations! you are done. Now your error will be gone.

PS:
By the way you can check Google Cloud SDK version by using this command -
gcloud version